# Windows 10 Fresh Install - Driver Missing (Coming from Mac)

Tags: windows-10, usb, desktop-computer, computer-building

Coming from using a Mac and I'm trying to install Windows 10 64 bit on my new build but getting error:

"A media driver your computer needs is missing" or "A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing"

I'm expecting to see a product activation screen here.

Here is my build:

```
MOBO: GIGABYTE B550 VISION D AM4 ATX
CPU: AMD AMD RYZEN 9 3900X WRAITHP
GPU: EVGA GT710 2GB HSF LP DVH PC (Only GPU left)
MEM: G.SKILL 32GB 2X16 D4 3600 TRZ RGB
HD1: SAMSUNG E 500GB 970EVO+NVME M.2 SSD
HD2: SEAGATE 2TB BARRACUDA 3.5" HD
```

1. I download the Windows ISO file on my Mac from - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO
2. Transferred the ISO file to various USBs using this method - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nhgjqbq_zYA&feature=youtu.be
3. Booted my PC with USB and going through Windows 10 load screen and getting error at this point.
4. Have tried switching to various USB ports. Tried on 2.0, 3.0, 3.2 ports and rebooting with no luck.
5. Updated my MOBO through BIOS and no luck here as well.

Would it be better for me to try to download Windows 10 on a PC and transfer to USB? Is downloading Windows 10 from a Mac causing this issue?

I feel like I'm running out of options or have missed some important step.

Currently transferring to what I think is a USB 2.0 as this was one solution I came across.

Looking for any kind of help, thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I formatted my USB using Disk Utility on my Mac to ExFat and after taking steps from step #2 above, it is now:

Universal Disk Format (UDF)

Comment: MBR or GPT?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  The Windows 10 installation environment has all the drivers you need.

Comment: @Ramhound I had to look up MBR or GPT. I didn't format my SSD or HD. It looks like I have to do some formatting to one/both? I will start looking towards this direction. Thank you

Comment: You can't install Windows to UDF or exFAT.  This is the case for the removable flash drive and the SDD you are installing Windows to.

Comment: @Ramhound What would be the proper way to partition my USB on my Mac using Disk Utility? I see my options are Format: Mac OS Extended/MS-DOS (FAT)/ExFat Scheme:GUID Partition Map/MBR/Apple Partition Map Selecting GUID allows me to also choose APFS. Thanks again

Comment: The video in question uses dd (a disk duplication tool) to copy the ISO file to the raw USB disk. This erases the GPT bootloader as well as the file system. I do not recommend that method. It seems good at first, but always leads to a UDF file system, which is not recommended for an USB install media.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Windows only supports GPT partition maps on current day UEFI bootloaders, and only MBR partition maps on older BIOS bootloaders.

Furthermore, so far I've only been successful with a FAT32 file system. In all other cases, I got the error as reported in the question.

So on MacOS, the best way is to format the USB disk using GPT partition map and MS-DOS(FAT) file system.

However, that does not get you out of trouble:

1. the Windows10ISO that you can download from the URL listed at step #1 gives and ISO disk with one 5.4 GByte large file (install.wim). However, FAT32 only supports files up to 4 Gbyte in size. It is possible to use the wimlib-imagex tool (in the wimlib tools) to split this large file in smaller chunks
2. If you format your disk this way, it may not be bootable (but I have not tested that).

In short, by far the easiest route is to borrow a friends Windows PC, and through these steps:

1. Go to the URL https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 (without 'ISO') and download the helper tool (MediaCreationTool).
2. In MediaCreationTool, be sure to select "Create installation media for another PC", and "ISO file". It is possible to create the USB stick directly in MediaCreationTool, but I found that is less reliable.
3. Download Rufus from rufus.ie, and install the ISO image to a USB stick. Rufus ensures that both the partition map and file system are compatible with UEFI.

Answer (score -1):

Im a little late. but I hope this could help someone else

I too tried everything you mentioned and it did not work.What did finally do the trick was to use Ventoy but the web version.

1. Run the script: "sudo ./VentoyWeb.sh" and follow the on screen
   instructions.
2. In the web page go to options and change the partition
   style to GPT (most important step).
3. Then just do the normal Ventoy
   setup.

with this you dont need windows pc to create the usb

Hope it works for anyone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).